# height of diagbox with tabularx and multirow

Tags: tables, tabularx, diagbox

How can get the diagbox on the whole width of the connected rows? Problem now,  its height seems to be only 2 textlines. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,diagbox,tabularx,blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox{Spalte}{Zeile}} & Text & Text\\
 & sehr sehr sehr sehr langer Text mit mehreren Zeilenumbrüchen & Text\\
Text & Text & Text\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you post a sketch of what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Like this? I've added some `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,diagbox,tabularx,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox[height=5\line]{\raisebox{2ex}{Spalte}}{ & & \\Zeile}} & Text & Text\\
 & sehr sehr sehr sehr langer Text mit mehreren Zeilenumbrüchen & Text \\
  \cline{1-1}
  Text & Text & Text \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to compile it both in Overleaf and in ShareLaTex but it gives `Use of \line doesn't match its definition.` and other errors.

Comment: @Bernard
Your output is exactly what I´d like to have, but I´ve also the problem with `\line` compiling your code.
How can I get the heigt of the tablerows?

Comment: Is there an other posibility to get (to sum) the exact heights of the tablerows?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Anyway, for a normal cell (without `\diagbox`), `\multirow` would require to count the number of lines in the adjacent cells. The first argument of \multirow (no of rows) supposes implicitly the adjacent cells are one-lined, so in practice, you have to count the lines

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The diagonal rule will always be as expected (it's drawn with PGF after the construction of the array).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{|w{c}{15mm}|X|X|}
\hline
\Block[draw]{2-1}{\diagbox{Spalte}{Zeile}} & Text & Text\\
 & sehr sehr sehr sehr langer Text mit mehreren Zeilenumbrüchen & Text\\
Text & Text & Text\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]