# Resize diagbox according to a cell with tabularray

Tags: tables, tabularray, diagbox

In the following code, the diagbox is not expanded to occupy the whole cell. I can modify height and width (optional parameter of diagbox), but which value can I give to this parameters ?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth,diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[2,c]X[4,c]X[2,c]},row{2-Z}={font=\footnotesize},vlines,hlines}
   A  & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  \diagbox[dir=NE,font=\LARGE\ttfamily]{}{20} \\
   B  & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jowe_19.I posted a second solution that hopefully answers your question, please have a look.

Comment: With nicematrix ? the answer of F. Pantigny https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324261/height-of-diagbox-with-tabularx-and-multirow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I return with a complete (I hope!!!) solution. I changed the table somehow to see the effect. You can change the numbers in X variable width (e.g. from 4 to 8, or from 2 to 4 or to 6), columns to see that the diagonal line follows them. You can delete some rows which are merged,make the appropriate changes, changing the coefficient (see below) to see that the height is adjusted automatically.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={X[2,c]X[4,c]X[2,c]},row{2-Z}={m,font=\footnotesize},vlines,hlines,cell{1}{2}={c=1,r=7}{c}}
        A  & \diagbox[dir=NE,font=\LARGE\ttfamily,width=\dimexpr\linewidth+2\tabcolsep,height=\dimexpr7\line+7\abovesep+7\belowsep+2pt]{}{20} \\%<- the number must be the same as the number of rows to be merged plus 2pt which is fixed.
        B  & \\
        C  & \\
        D  & \\
        E  & \\
        F  & \\
        G  & \\
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used variable width columns, so it was a try and error procedure to find the optimal width and height of the line. And with some small changes based on your code we have the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth,diagbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={X[2,c]X[4,c]X[2,c]},row{2-Z}={m,font=\footnotesize},vlines,hlines,cell{1}{2}={c=1,r=2}{c}}
        A  & \diagbox[dir=NE,font=\LARGE\ttfamily,width=8.25cm,height=2.6\line]{}{20} \\
        B  & \\
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no way to compute the ideal width and height ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a way that works with any variable width column. For fixed width columns things are easier.